# парсер cookie по url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется [url](https://ocservice.taobao.com/cookieController/processUserCookie?site=CN_zh-CN_CNY_156&callback=jsonp_1546706091271_92560)
необходимо парсить cookie на javascrip или на jquery, как это можно сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: url не имеет к cookie никакого отношения

Comment: @andreymal как мне получить тогда куки выделенной в картинке?

Comment: Куки от текущего сайта можно прочитать в `window.document.cookie` и только те, которые сайт разрешил прочитать. Никакие другие куки читать невозможно

Comment: А нельзя ли передать `url` функции `window.document.cookie` ?

Comment: Это не функция, а строка, поэтому нельзя. И нигде не будет можно, потому что скрипты не имеют права читать какие угодно куки в целях безопасности